# Cannot connect to server to show profile or stats

Tags: psn, ps4, warframe

On PS4, the Warframe game works but accessing my profile or profiles of other players always fails with a connection error. I am not talking about the PSN profile which is displayed just fine but the Warframe profile and stat pages in-game. Is this a port, NAT or privacy setting issue?

Update 16 fixed this issue finally!

Comment: I think it's neither one of these issues but server sided

Comment: look here https://forums.warframe.com/index.php?/topic/350087-i-have-problems-trying-to-see-my-profile/ on january 3rd ppl still got the same problem. One more thing: Warframe posted "We're investigating the connectivity issues and login errors occurring within the past hour on console - apologies for the frustration!" on their twitter account  2 days ago so it's possible they still have some problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you problems are server sided.

[Warframe posted about server issues](https://twitter.com/playwarframe) 2 days ago but didn't say anything about a fix, so its close that the problems are still there.

Furthermore it seems like you're not the only one who can't see other profiles and the problem seems to be there for a while now. [Here is a Thread about your Problem.](https://forums.warframe.com/index.php?/topic/350087-i-have-problems-trying-to-see-my-profile/)